# post values through mvc repeater

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

**Form-**

```
@using IEnumerable<Myapplication.Models.CardModel>
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {

          <form method="post" action="/Upload/EditCard/?cardID=@item.cardID" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <h3>
                                        Change Title-
                                    </h3>
                                    <div class="display-field">
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.cardTitle)
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(cardTitle => item.cardTitle)
                                    </div>
                                     <img src="@item.cardFilePath" />
                                    <input type="submit">
                          </form>
    }
```

**Method-**
 [HttpPost]

```
public void EditCard(CardModel card, HttpPostedFileBase file) {}
```

Where in form I am sending values through this form, and `cardID` is sent in form's url parameter.

For other value like `cardTitle` is coming null in `EditCard` Method.

How do I get this value using repeater?

However when data is not `IEnumerable` type , then I was able to send value through form directly as-

@using Myapplication.Models.CardModel

```
      <form method="post" action="/Upload/EditCard/?cardID=@Model.cardID" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <h3>
                                    Change Title-
                                </h3>
                                <div class="display-field">
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.cardTitle)
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.cardTitle)
                                </div>
                                 <img src="@Model.cardFilePath" />
                                    <input type="submit">
                      </form>
}
```

but In case of repeater values don't come at method. **As soon as i change values of title, or anything else, The values comes old one.**

From the pictures-

[image]

**And server code-**

[image]

As you can see from 1st picture that, Form is editable for one record from the list. As soon as I change something in i.e. **Title to -->** `2nd Upload` to `2nd Uploadsssss`

Then this values is null at server side. I mean this form don't send values of it.

**Note-**

However I can send values in URL through parameters. But if I do change in something like Title or `aboutCard` model value. The form keeps sending only those values which has come by default while the form was rendered.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, need your help

Comment: In ur second code what is @item.cardFilePath? is should me @Model.cardFilePath

Comment: @NitinVarpe, Yeah a mistake was there.

Comment: @NitinVarpe, As you see in second code (only for one record) I can send and get values at server side. But while iterating it in loop values are not sent to method.

Comment: Yep. Do u want to create multiple forms?

Comment: @NitinVarpe, I have edited the question for better understanding.

Comment: Please check my answer, relly if that does trick

Comment: @user3163213, for each `cardTitle` property you're defining two input elements: one `type="hidden"` and one `type="text"`. Since you're rendering the text box anyway, take the hidden input out. They both have the same name so the auto binder tries to create a list for the `cardTitle` property and it is unable to cast this list to your (I assume `string`) property and that's why you get `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `foreach` use `for` loop. To apply indexing you would need to convert Model to List

```
  @{ var list=Model.ToList();)

@for(var i = 1;i <= list.Count();i++)
{   

  <form method="post" action="/Upload/EditCard/?cardID=@list[i].cardID" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <h3>
                                Change Title-
                            </h3>
                            <div class="display-field">
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => list[i].cardTitle)
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> list[i].cardTitle)
                            </div>
                             <img src="@list[i].cardFilePath" />
                                <input type="submit">
  </form>

}
```

Update..

I have tested same but doesnt work. I have created workaround check if that helps.

In controller get title using cardId

```
 var title=Request["[" + (model.cardTitle)+ "].cardTitle"];
```

Same thing can be done for other properties for model.

Note that i have changed `for` loop, index now starts with 1

Answer (score 1):

You need to change IEnumerable to IList, and then you'll be able to bind Model correctly by index.

See this working exaple.

**View Page**

```
@model IList<MvcApplication3.Models.CardModel>

@using (Html.BeginForm("EditCard", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) 
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].CardID)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(cardTitle => Model[i].CardTitle)
        <img src="@Model[i].CardFilePath" />
        <input type="file" name="files"> 
    }
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
}
```

**Controller**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public void EditCard(IList<CardModel> cm, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
        {
            string strfile = string.Empty;
            string cardTitle = string.Empty;
            if (files != null)
            {
                foreach (var file in files) //loop through to get posted file
                {
                    strfile = file.FileName;
                }
            }
            if (cm != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in cm) //loop through to get CardModel fields
                {
                    cardTitle = item.CardTitle;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this helps in solving your problem. I tried this and it works really well.

The Model

```
public class CardFileModel
{
    public int CardId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

Index Action

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   List<CardFileModel> cards = new List<CardFileModel>
   {
       new CardFileModel{ CardId =1 , Name="Card1"  },
       new CardFileModel{ CardId =2 , Name="Card2"  }
   };

   return View(cards);
}
```

Home View

```
@model List<MVC3Stack.Models.CardFileModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
    <div>
        <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[i].CardId)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[i].Name)
        </div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[i].File, new { type = "file" })
        <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
    </div>
    }
}
```

index post action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<CardFileModel> card)
{
    //Access your card file from the list. 
    var name = card.FirstOrDefault().Name;
    return View();
}
```

And here are the results in the quick watch

[image: Quick Watch snapshot]

Hope this helps.