# Binding an array ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Model

```
public class person
{
    public string name {get; set;}
    public int age{get; set;}
    public List<int> Keys {get; set;}
}
```

In my view I have this code

```
@using Person

<form id= "form1" action = "@Url.Action("Update", Model)" method ="@FormMethod.Post">
   @Html.editorfor(x => x.name);
   @Html.editorfor(x => x.address);

   @for(var i = 0; i < Model.Keys.Count; i++)
   {
     @Html.Hiddenfor(x => x.Keys[i]);
   }
</form>
```

my controller code is

```
public ActionResult Update(Person p)
{
  //the person key is equal to the person age
  p.Keys.Add(p.age);

  return View(p);
}
```

This does return the value of keys to the model, but I need to keep all values of Keys and when the user submits the form again the Keys array is null. For my task I need Keys to keep all record changes of age for that view not just the most recent. why will my model no bind or remember the array why does it forget the array values every time the form is submitted? I thought I had bind it, it should not be null but have all values entered for Keys.

Comment: I don't see any code in your Update method that suggests you are saving the form data.  In fact, quite the opposite; your code suggests a GET, not a POST.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am adding the integer age to the Model property Keys and returning it to the view, that should save it since I am using a Person Model on the view?

Comment: You're missing a close parenthesis in your Hiddenfor.  Might that have something to do with it?  (surely it would have thrown an exception).

Comment: @RobertHarvey no that was just my bad copy and paste skills. What I really am trying to do is make a dynamic list until the user is ready to save it. this has proven to be difficult when going for view to controller data is not being stored and passed the way I thought it would.

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis with your form action before method. Another copy/paste error? Also you have two different `I`/`i` variables in your `for` loop. As far as Robert Harvey's comment, yes you are "saving" it to the model that's going back to the new view, but you're not storing that in your database at all.

Comment: `action = "@Url.Action("Update", Model)` does not make sense.  Why would you pass the model to RouteValues?

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET MVC are you using? 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5?

Comment: @ErikPhilips I thought the only way to preserve model values was to make sure to pass the model to the control then pass it back to the view or you will loose your model state.

Comment: @GuillermoGutiérrez I am using MVC 4 or 5

Comment: @krillgar even thought I do not save it to database, the data should still persist, I am passing it from view to controller and controller to view.

Comment: @user3860872 OK, I just wanted to make sure you were aware of that distinction.

Comment: @user3860872 if you want to preserve values on post back they need to be on the form.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I do not understand what you mean by on the form?

Comment: They need to be passed as input values using `<input>` or `<textarea>`, complex models cannot be passed using routevalues.

Comment: @ErikPhilips "@Html.Hiddenfor" I believe is a input value, it is just not visible.

Comment: The code as is, should not even compile.  There needs to be at a bare minimum surrounding text element: `<text>@Html.Hiddenfor(x => x.Keys[i])</text>`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I believe you are mistaken, the html helper takes care of that and it does compile and work with just the html helper wrap in a form.

Comment: Apparently Razor 2.0 does not [require surrounding text anymore](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax).

Answer (score 1):

In the view, try to define the hidden keys this way:

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.Keys.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.Hidden("Keys", Model.Keys[i])
}
```

I'm not sure, but maybe the `HiddenFor` method is setting the field name unnapropiately for the model binder to recognize it. Maybe it only works for collections of complex types.

Comment: The code as is, should not even compile. There needs to be at a bare minimum surrounding text element: `<text>@Html.Hidden("Keys", Model.Keys[i])</text>`.

Comment: Actually it does as is. In this case the `text` element is optional, but not required.

Answer (score 0):

I would use IList instead and also need to re-initialize Person.Keys property again. Visit [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372162/post-values-through-mvc-repeater/22526738#22526738) for example.

**Example**

```
public ActionResult Update(Person p, IList<int> keys)
{
    p.Keys = keys;
    return View(p);
}
```